# Microsoft Text translator API is not working for android?

Tags: android

[Microsoft-translator-api] Error retrieving translation : Unable to resolve host "data market.access control.windows.net": No address associated with host name

Answer (score 0):

The app authentication method for the API has changed.

See this article for migration instructions: https://cognitive.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/1128340-announcements-microsoft-translator-moves-to-the-a